# Switching from first layout to second using layoutInflater: onclicklistner crashing the activity

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener

In this application i am displaying 6 images randomly from an array containing drawables(named vmarray[12] ) and after 1 minute(using runnable postdelayed) switching is performed to another layout containing a single button with id BUTTON1 and setting the button background to one of the image from the earlier displayed images. I am using LAYOUTINFLATER for switching between layouts

On that button (Button1) onclick i want to do some work, but the PROBLEM IS when i implement onclicklistener and onclick method, the app crashes.

IF i remove the implements onclicklistener everything runs fine. The BUTTON1 is located perfectely through findviewbyid and its background correctly sets to an image. BUT Implementing onclicklister is crashing the app.

```
    here is the code..

   int[] vmarray= {R.drawable.vm1bulb, R.drawable.vm2chair, R.drawable.vm3comb,
   R.drawable.vm4cycle,R.drawable.vm5dairy,R.drawable.vm6fan,R.drawable.vm7mobile,
   R.drawable.vm8pen,R.drawable.vm9shoes,R.drawable.vm10toothbrush,  
    R.drawable.vm11bangle, R.drawable.vm12watch};

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


 inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

 setContentView(R.layout.cacrvisualmem);

 firstview =(LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.firsthumlayout);

 secondview = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.cacrvisualmempart1, null);

   for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
     { 
     final int a = i;
     button_var[a] = (Button)findViewById(idArray[a]); 
     }


    // IN FIRST LAYOUT, THERE ARE 6 BUTTONS AND THEIR BACKGROUND IS RANDOMLY SET      
   //   DRAWABLES FROM ARRAY "vmarray". the following code is for that

     Random randomGenerator = new Random();
      Random rand6 = new Random();

     while (numbers.size() < 6) {
     random1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(12);
     random2 = rand6.nextInt(6);

      if (!numbers.contains(random1) && (!numbers2.contains(random2))) 
       {
           numbers.add(random1);

           numbers2.add(random2);  

           b[random2].setBackgroundResource(vmarray[random1]);
           count++;         

        }//if ends
     }//while ends

     Handler changeview = new Handler();

     Runnable r1 = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // NOW, here, after 1 minute, second view will be inflated and button1  
            //  background is set to one the image from the array

            setContentView(secondview);

            b11=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

            queryrandvar=queryrand.nextInt(12);

            switch(queryrandvar)
            {
            case 0:
                b11.setBackgroundResource(vmarray[0]);
                queryval=0;
                break;
            case 1:
                b11.setBackgroundResource(vmarray[1]);
                queryval=1;
                break;
            case 2:
                b11.setBackgroundResource(vmarray[2]);
                queryval=2;
                break;
            case 3:
                b11.setBackgroundResource(vmarray[3]);
                queryval=3;
                break;
            case 4:
                b11.setBackgroundResource(vmarray[4]);
                queryval=4;
                break;
            case 5:
                b11.setBackgroundResource(vmarray[5]);
                queryval= 5;
                break;
            case 6:
                b11.setBackgroundResource(vmarray[6]);
                queryval= 6;
                break;
            case 7:
                b11.setBackgroundResource(vmarray[7]);
                queryval= 7;
                break;
            case 8:
                b11.setBackgroundResource(vmarray[8]);
                queryval= 8;
                break;
            case 9:
                b11.setBackgroundResource(vmarray[9]);
                queryval= 9;
                break;
            case 10:
                b11.setBackgroundResource(vmarray[10]);
                queryval= 10;
                break;
            case 11:
                b11.setBackgroundResource(vmarray[11]);
                queryval= 11;
                break;

        }//switch ends


        }//run ends
     };//runnable ends

     b11.setOnClickListener(null);

     changeview.postDelayed(r1,10000);

 } //on create method ends here



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  switch(v.getId())
  {
  case R.id.button1:
     {

      b11.setBackgroundResource(vmarray[1]);

      break;
     }

  }//switch ends
}//onclick ends
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it.inside runnable after switch case i have put  the following and button onclick is working.RUNING FINE WITH NO APP CRASH

```
                b11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                b11.setBackgroundResource(vmarray[0]); //SOME RANDOM IMAGE FOR CHECKING
                }
             });
```